# MySQL 5.5 - Select rows where record changes

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have got this table and I need to produce the line with the last A and first B and then last B and first A. Expected results are here:

```
    ID | Date       | OPS
     6 | 2018-12-20 | A
     7 | 2018-12-20 | B
    11 | 2018-12-24 | B
    12 | 2018-12-25 | A
```

I have tried to do with the below code with nil luck. **I cannot use analytic functions** like ROW_NUMBER(), LEAD () or LAG ().

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, t1.OPS
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ts1.OPS
        FROM T1 ts1
        JOIN T1 tx1 ON ts1.OPS = tx1.OPS
    ) t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ts2.OPS
        FROM T1 ts2
        JOIN T1 tx2 ON ts2.OPS = tx2.OPS
    ) t2 on t1.OPS <= t2.OPS
    GROUP BY t1.OPS
) tt ON T1.OPS = tt.OPS
```

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    ID int,
    Date1 date,
    OPS CHAR
);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
( 1, '2018-12-17', 'A'),
( 2, '2018-12-18', 'A'),
( 3, '2018-12-19', 'A'),
( 4, '2018-12-19', 'A'),
( 5, '2018-12-19', 'A'),
( 6, '2018-12-20', 'A'),
( 7, '2018-12-20', 'B'),
( 8, '2018-12-21', 'B'),
( 9, '2018-12-22', 'B'),
(10, '2018-12-23', 'B'),
(11, '2018-12-24', 'B'),
(12, '2018-12-25', 'A'),
(13, '2018-12-26', 'A'),
(14, '2018-12-27', 'A'),
(15, '2018-12-28', 'A');
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `LEAD` and `LAG` and considering that you have multiple records per-date you could use a <del>horrendous</del> simplified solution **which assumes that the records are ordered by `id` instead of date**. It does not require ids to be contiguous and works for more than two ops values:

```
SELECT *
FROM t AS ref
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS lag
    WHERE ops <> ref.ops
    AND id < ref.id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t AS tmp
        WHERE id > lag.ID
        AND id < ref.id
    )
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS led
    WHERE ops <> ref.ops
    AND id > ref.id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t AS tmp
        WHERE id < led.ID
        AND id > ref.id
    )
)
```

Basically for each row, the query searches all previous rows where ids do not match then determines if there is a row in between. It searches forward likewise.

Comment: It gives 'Table 'test.t' doesn't exist'

Comment: Obviously. replace `t` with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following logic, which phrases your question using a series of unions:

```
(SELECT ID, Date1, OPS FROM T1 WHERE OPS = 'B' ORDER BY Date1 LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT ID, Date1, OPS FROM T1
WHERE OPS = 'A' AND Date1 <= (SELECT MIN(Date1) FROM T1 WHERE OPS = 'B')
ORDER BY Date1 DESC LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT ID, Date1, OPS FROM T1 WHERE OPS = 'B' ORDER BY Date1 DESC LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT ID, Date1, OPS FROM T1
WHERE OPS = 'A' AND Date1 >= (SELECT MAX(Date1) FROM T1 WHERE OPS = 'B')
ORDER BY Date1 LIMIT 1)

ORDER BY Date1, OPS;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note generally that this is a gaps and islands problem.  These are very difficult to handle without using analytic functions, which you appear to not have available.  If you were using MySQL 8+, then we could phrase a much cleaner looking query.

Comment: Any way of not having LIMIT in the code. Other then that works like magic

Comment: @Kalenji Yes, I could write the above without using `LIMIT`, but the query would then be much more verbose and ugly.  Really, if you have the need for this type of query you should seriously upgrade to MySQL 8+ and then use analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated subquery that computed the min and max ids for each ops, like

```
SELECT t.*
FROM T1 t
WHERE
    t.id IN (
        SELECT MIN(id) FROM T1 WHERE ops = t.ops
        UNION ALL SELECT MAX(id) FROM T1 WHERE ops = t.ops
    )
ORDER BY t.ops, t.id DESC
```

Comment: It gives ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @Kalenji : query updated, pls let me know if it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

if we are allowed max and min function, then it is pretty easy to calculate these 4 individually and union the individual results.

-- To select last A
select ID, Date1, OPS
  from test_t1
 where test_t1.OPS = 'A'
   and test_t1.Date1 in
       (
        select max(t1_a.Date1) as Date1
          from
               (select ID, Date1, OPS 
                  from test_t1
                 where OPS = 'A') t1_a inner join
               (select min(Date1) as Date1
                  from test_t1
                  where OPS = 'B') t1_min_b
                on t1_a.Date1 <= t1_min_b.Date1
       )
union

-- To select first B

select ID, Date1, OPS
  from test_t1
 where test_t1.OPS = 'B'
   and test_t1.Date1 in
       (
        select min(Date1) as Date1
          from test_t1
         where OPS = 'B'
       ) 
union
/*
To select last B
*/
select ID, Date1, OPS
  from test_t1
 where test_t1.OPS = 'B'
   and test_t1.Date1 in
       (
        select max(Date1) as Date1
          from test_t1
         where OPS = 'B'
       ) 
union
/*
To select first A
*/
select ID, Date1, OPS
  from test_t1
 where test_t1.OPS = 'A'
   and test_t1.Date1 in
       (
        select min(t1_a.Date1) as Date1
          from
               (select ID, Date1, OPS 
                  from test_t1
                 where OPS = 'A') t1_a inner join
               (select max(Date1) as Date1
                  from test_t1
                  where OPS = 'B') t1_max_b
                on t1_a.Date1 >= t1_max_b.Date1
       )
;

Comment: It gives ERROR 1064 (42000):

Comment: replace test_t1 table name from your table name t1 and replace or remove the comments starting  with -- and /* combination